# SSRS 2005 Report with Oracle DB - Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have seen this issue discussed in various places, but have yet to see a actual solution or explanation to this error. I can't figure out what is causing the error, my query runs fine independently, and this report was working perfectly as is or with some very minor changes.

```
SELECT wo.wonum, wo.worktype, wo.description wo_description, wo.targcompdate,     wo.assetnum, wo.estlabhrs, wo.actlabhrs, wo.actfinish,  s.siteid, s.description     s_description, round((wo.targcompdate - sysdate), 0) DaysTillDue
FROM workorder wo
INNER JOIN site s on wo.siteid = s.siteid
WHERE 
wo.istask = '0'
 and wo.status in ('APPR','INPRG','WAPPR','WMATL','WSCH','APPR''EVALUATED','INPRG','ISOLATED','WAPPR','WMATL'    ,'WSCH','APPR','EVALUATED','INPRG',     'ISOLATED','WAPPR','WMATL','WSCH','APPR','EVALUATED','INPRG','ISOLATED','WAPPR','WMATL','WS    CH','WWAP')
 and  wo.siteid = :site_param
 and (:worktype_param is NULL or wo.worktype = :worktype_param) 
and ((
(:High_Day is NULL or ( (wo.targcompdate - sysdate) <= :High_Day)) 
and (:start_date is NULL or targcompdate >= :start_date)
and (:end_date is NULL or targcompdate <= :end_date))
or targcompdate is NULL)
```

The :worktype_param and :site_param are pulled in from other data sets and presented as a drop down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So am an not sure the reason, but taking these fields out of the select statement took care of the issue: 
s.description s_description, round((wo.targcompdate - sysdate), 0) DaysTillDue
FROM workorder wo

If anyone still has info on what causes this that'd be awesome, thanks.